# Xamarin ImageSource in ListView not updating

Tags: xamarin

I have a ListView that contains images, the images are fetched from a server. The first API call I make gets the data in `var people`. I load the listview with a placeholder image, then run the 2nd API call to get the images for each item in the listview. I receive a byte[] as the image, and I convert it to an ImageSource. I have a search button at the top of the page that I set binding to `TempImage` which uses the byte[] as its source, and it changes to the images that are loaded. So the conversion of byte[] to ImageSource is fine. The initial setting of `p.PictureImageSource = "name_circle.png"` also works correctly. However, setting `p.PictureImageSource` to the converted byte[] does NOT work. It never changes from the initial `"name_circle.png"`. Any ideas?

```
                        var people = peopleModel.Response;

                        if(people.Count == 0)
                        {
                            ShowNoResults = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ShowNoResults = false;
                            Results = peopleModel.Response;
                            foreach (PersonViewModel p in Results)
                            {
                                p.Initials = p.FirstName[0].ToString() + p.LastName[0];
                                p.PictureImageSource = "name_circle.png";
                            }

                        }

                        //must do 2 seperate loops so the initials load before going on with 2nd search
                        foreach (PersonViewModel p in Results)
                        {
                            IsBusy = false;
                            var peopleImage = await peopleService.GetPersonImage("p.Email");

                            if ((peopleImage.Error == null) && (peopleImage.Response != null))
                            {
                                p.Picture = peopleImage.Response;

                                byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])peopleImage.Response;
                                p.PictureImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
                                TempImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
                            }

                        }

                        OnPropertyChanged();
```

-

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public WorkstationViewModel WorkstationDetail { get; set; }

        public List<PointViewModel> Points { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
        public string SiteID { get; set; }
        public string BuildingID { get; set; }
        public string FloorNumber { get; set; }
        public string FloorID { get; set; }
        public string Workstation { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        public ImageSource PictureImageSource { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: What does your `PersonViewModel` looks like?

Comment: It's a public class with attributes `public string Email`, `public byte[] Picture`, and `public ImageSource PictureImageSource`.

Comment: Does `PersonViewModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @WillNasby actually I wanted to see the code to address what @mark just asked. Your `PersonViewModel` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the update of one of its properties fires the notification.

Comment: Sorry, I added the full code. I added `INotifyPropertyChanged` however the problem persists. Everything else is updating fine though (Name, Initials, etc).

Comment: You might also need to do the full implementation of the properties (unless you are using Fody). Btw as a test in the second loop where you change you `PictureImageSource` try to also change the `p.Initials` to any value.. does it update?

Comment: You're right, nothing is updating. Sad thing is I remember having a similar problem a year ago, and I solved it by setting the data source of the listview to null and then set it back to the complete value once I get the 2nd set of data from the API. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Apineda was correct in thinking the listview wasn't refreshing at all with the new data. I separated the two API calls into two different methods (not sure if this part is entirely necessary). After the completion of the 2nd call, I set the listview's `ItemSource` to null, then back to the `Results` value, forcing a refreshing. Now the images show.

```
searchGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async (s, e) => {
                await _viewModel.GetResults();
                await _viewModel.GetImagesForResults();
                resultsListView.ItemsSource = null;
                resultsListView.ItemsSource = _viewModel.Results;
            };
```